# Wikidata Query Service reliability

Tags: wikidata, sparql

I encountered a partially incorrect result set from Wikidata Query Service.

Requested Wikipedia article urls were missing for an item where this information existed, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33178986/wikidata-query-service-incomplete-result-wikipedia-url-missing

A day later the service was returning the urls.

What may have been the reason for the error?

When is the service expected to leave beta status and to become fully reliable?

And where can I find information about

- temporary problems (such as the one mentioned above)
- progress and current status
- future plans and milestones

of Wikidata Query Service?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is [an error in loading data](https://lists.wikimedia.org/pipermail/wikidata-tech/2015-October/000885.html). It was a temporary problem, now fixed.

The information about future plans and work on WDQS can be found on [Wikimedia Discovery team page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikimedia_Discovery#Wikidata_Query_Service_.28WDQS.29) and [Phabricator board](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/tag/wikidata-query-service/).